# Propagating "daemon"-status to all child-threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

If I have a `Thread` object, I can call `setDaemon(true)` on it to mark that this thread should not prevent application shutdown if all other non-daemon threads have terminated.

Is it possible to make this behavior automatically trickle down to all child-threads? I.e. if I have a thread that is marked as a daemon-thread, is there some way to enforce that all threads spawned by this thread are also automatically marked as daemon-threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to make this behavior automatically trickle down to all
>   child-threads?

You don't need to do that since it is by default:

> The newly created thread is initially marked as being a daemon thread
>   if and only if the thread creating it is currently marked as a daemon
>   thread. The method setDaemon may be used to change whether or not a
>   thread is a daemon.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/pbp1.1.2/jsr217/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Hmmm... looks correct... I guess I need to go looking through my code why this isn't working for me...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ThreadGroup`, then set the ThreadGroup to daemon: `myThreadGroup.setDaemon(true)` and then use this TreadGroup when you create a new Thread:

```
ThreadGroup myThreadGroup = new ThreadGroup(...);
myThreadGroup.setDaemon(true);

// ... and every time you create a thread:
Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadGroup, "My #n Thread") { ... };
// ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over the creation of the child-thread... But in general a good idea!