# Proxy connection issue in JDK5..UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to an external server from Java (JDK5) server, though proxy.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html (3rd section).

```
java.net.Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new java.net.InetSocketAddress("WHQPROXYPOOL", 80));
java.net.HttpURLConnection con = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL("https://performancemanager8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/FOPayGroup?$format=json").openConnection(proxy);
```

But I am getting error, "UnsupportedOperationException, Method not implemented".
When I check Java class (JDK5) URLStreamHandler

```
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u, Proxy p) throws IOException {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented.");
}
```

How can I connect to target server through proxy?

Comment: What version is your JDK? I am able to connect fine to the above server with the latest version of JDK 5 update 22.

Comment: My server, where the program runs, is on JDK 5, update 22. URLStreamHandler is abstract class. Where will be implementation class and how will JDK identify it?

Comment: which line is throwing the exception the second one?

Comment: Yes. Second line. .openConnection(proxy) will call openConnection(Proxy proxy) of class URL, it will call openConnection(URL u, Proxy p) of abstract class URLStreamHandler.

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/presenceofit.com.au/document/d/1U7C_33pHARpPqXZXPeETRUFdKuRIx3EkW9VRgWvTgvc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/presenceofit.com.au/document/d/1U7C_33pHARpPqXZXPeETRUFdKuRIx3EkW9VRgWvTgvc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Now, above link is accessible.

Comment: looks like this is specific to XI. They must not be using the default `Protocol Handler` class supplied with the JDK. They must have done their own implementation. When I have time I will try to take a look at the stacktrace and dissect it and see if I can pull any useful information from the stacktrace.

Comment: Great analysis. I guessed same thing from the start. URLStreamHandler is abstract class and there must be some implementation. I do know, how JDK will know where implementation class is present. Yes, XI might have there own implementation. Have to find out how XI picks up implantation class Handler.

Comment: I posted what I think might solve your problem...let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this @RaghuVamseedhar:

```
java.net.Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new java.net.InetSocketAddress("WHQPROXYPOOL", 80));
java.net.HttpURLConnection con = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL(null, "https://performancemanager8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/FOPayGroup?$format=json", new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler()).openConnection(proxy);
```

I got this code to get the default sun HTTP Handler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018891/4028085)